CSS transition applied through JavaScript problem
My button transition to the second one is good and working but I want the background to be included in the transition, for example, In the first page I have blue background, A description box, and a "Get Started" button. I want the background color to change into red with the same transition with my button and description box then vice versa when I get to the second page. Also, my "home" button in the second page is not working, I mean the transition isn't applied when I click it. I want everything to slide up and down.


const getStartedButton = document.getElementById("getStartedButton");
const homeButton = document.getElementById("homeButton");
const desc = document.querySelector(".description");
const slideButton = document.querySelector(".slide");

// Event listener for the get started button
getStartedButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  desc.classList.add("hide-description"); // Add class to hide description
  slideButton.classList.add("hide-button"); // Add class to hide button
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector(".about").classList.add("show-about"); // Add class to show 'about' section after transition ends
    document.querySelector(".homebut").classList.add("show-homebut");
    desc.style.display = "none";
    slideButton.style.display = "none";
  }, 2000); // Adjust this time to match the duration of the transition in CSS
});

// Event listener for the home button
homeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".about").classList.remove("show-about"); // Remove class to hide 'about' section
  document.querySelector(".homebut").classList.remove("show-homebut");
  setTimeout(function() {
    desc.classList.remove("hide-description"); // Remove class to show description
    slideButton.classList.remove("hide-button"); // Remove class to show button
    desc.style.display = "block";
    slideButton.style.display = "block";
  }, 2000); // Adjust this time to match the duration of the transition in CSS
});
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

.description {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 50px;
  /* shorthand for margin */
  width: 500px;
  height: 225px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 75px 25px;
  /* shorthand for padding */
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(10, 135, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 98, 0, 1) 45%, rgba(25, 179, 0, 1) 92%);
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 25px;
  /* Transition for description opacity */
}

.hide-description {
  animation: myAnim 2s ease-in-out 1s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes myAnim {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {
    transform: translateY(-190vh);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-200vh);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.slide {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100vh;
  /* shorthand for margin */
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(10, 135, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 98, 0, 1) 45%, rgba(25, 179, 0, 1) 92%);
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  /* Add your button styling here */
}

.hide-button {
  animation: myAnim 2s ease-in-out 1s 1 normal forwards;
}

.about {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 45%;
  left: 33.3%;
  transform: translate(50%, 200vh);
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 225px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 75px 25px;
  /* shorthand for padding */
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(10, 135, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 98, 0, 1) 45%, rgba(25, 179, 0, 1) 92%);
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 25px;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.show-about {
  animation: myAnim1 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal both;
}

@keyframes myAnim1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}

.homebut {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 85vh;
  margin-left: 46%;
  /* shorthand for margin */
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(10, 135, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(217, 98, 0, 1) 45%, rgba(25, 179, 0, 1) 92%);
  color: aliceblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  /* Add your button styling here */
}

.show-homebut {
  animation: myAnim2 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal both;
}

@keyframes myAnim2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}

.show-slide {
  animation: myAnim3 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal both;
}

@keyframes myAnim3 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
}

.show-description {
  animation: myAnim4 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal both;
}

@keyframes myAnim4 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
}
<div class="description">Yusisista Minimap is a web-based application that provides students and visitors with easy access to navigate the UCC Congress campus, allowing them to locate desired facilities, offices, and rooms with ease and efficiency.</div>

<button id="getStartedButton" class="slide">Get started</button>

<div class="about">HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII</div>
<button id="homeButton" class="homebut">Home</button>



